# limit of the root of a sequence

Tags: calculus, limits

When is $\sqrt{\lim (a_n)} $ equal to $\lim(\sqrt {a_n} )$? My $a_n$ is a sequence of natural numbers, I think this happens when the sequence is positive or continuous but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The root of $a_n$ is only defined if $a_n$ is positive...

Comment: So does the sequence have to be continuous?

Comment: @Programmingfreak What's your definition of continuity over $\mathbb{N}\,$? A sequence of natural numbers converges *iff* it eventually goes constant.

Comment: That the sequence limit at a point is equal to the sequence value at that point.

Answer (score 1):

If $\forall n\in\Bbb N : a_n\ge 0$ and $\exists\lim{a_n}$,
$$\lim\sqrt{a_n} = \sqrt{\lim{a_n}}$$
because the square root is a continuous function.

Comment: Martin. Just commented on something similar